# Background Worker How To

Tags: c#, asp.net, backgroundworker

I'm trying to implement background worker into my program, so that it wont freeze when i run the program and starts retrieving the data I need.

I'm not quite sure how background worker works.

Comment: In MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx you have a good example and explanation on how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background workers are threads that run in the background and do work without interrupting/blocking your main thread.

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

In quick terms:

In DoWork do your blocking operation. Whenever you can, report how far through you are with the operation using `(sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(50);` for example to report 50% completion.

You can have your main thread subscribe to the "ProgressChanged" event, which can update GUI or do other tasks which should occur when the progress has changed.

Comment: im not sure what to implement into this section of my code

        private void fNameBrowser(string fName, string dir)
        {

        }

Comment: I have absolutely no way to know how your code works unless you post some

Comment: Posted! My application is a file browser. Once a directory is enter it needs the background worker to continue updating, instead of freezing.